# SSMS Plugin for making keywords all caps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there a SSMS plugin for automatically converting T-SQL keywords into all caps? Preferably, one that converts as I type. Holding the shift key or toggling caps lock is a pain.

Comment: Not an answer, but just making sure you're aware that ctrl+shift+u will transform selection to uppercase. It helps a bit.

Comment: Check out SQLPrompt by red-gate.com.  It's not free but I find it incredibly useful.  It is like super intellisense and provides a ton of metadata about your objects as you code.  You can do alot of customization to get the code format you want.  And yes, by default it will make all keywords uppercase as you type.  Not sure if I can link a video but here is 30 seconds of SQL Prompt:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UJ3I8KQTu4

Comment: Yep, I know about ctrl+shift+u.

Comment: Bostaevski - would you post your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Do you have a background in Oracle by any chance? The database platform THAT_CAN_ONLY_SHOUT haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out SQLPrompt by red-gate.com. It's not free but I find it incredibly useful. It is like super intellisense and provides a ton of metadata about your objects as you code. You can do alot of customization to get the code format you want. And yes, by default it will make all keywords uppercase as you type. Not sure if I can link a video but here is 30 seconds of SQL Prompt:

youtube.com/watch?v=6UJ3I8KQTu4

Answer (score 0):

I usually write it in Notepad ++ and use the Poor mans TSQL plugin to do that.
Plus as long as the the same file is open in both notepad++ and SSMS they will update each other if you make any changes.

The only downside is that you don't get intellisense.

Comment: You can also install the Poor mans TSQL plugin into SSMS, see here: [http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx). I'm pretty sure this is the legit page for the plugin.